# Saving preference values from table

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, preferences

I'm having a preference page, which extends `PreferencePage` (not
`FieldEditorPreferencePage`), and implements `IWorkbenchPreferencePage`.
I have a table in my preference page and user can add any number of rows
to the table. All the rows in the table have to persistence in the
preference store. I see only `setValue()` methods in the preference. The
problem is I don't know the number of rows in advance and it is dynamic.
Can someone tell me how to save the values in the table into the
preference store?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store a string which contains contents of all rows (delimited, so that you can break it back into rows when needed).